# how to setup “Get started” button in facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, postman, bots

I m trying to use postman
link:https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/messages?access_token=my_token

```
{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload": "Hi, I am bot"
  }
}
```

in raw JSON body

but getting this response

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (Page)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "AtFh2_fJ2sxkeU8k-2aNJGl"
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re making your request against the wrong endpoint there.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api

Comment: do you mean by https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN> this one i tried it but it send me ```{"data":[]}```

Comment: Did you make a POST or a GET request …?

Comment: @misorude OMG I forget about it thank you very much its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the little rundown how to put **get started** button , I hope its help:
**Using postman:**

1. Start by changing the type by choosing a POST request: (one of the
   problems that solve my issue thanks to @misorude
2. Define a Post request to this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

As @misorude notice my another problem check endpoint from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api

3. In the BODY section:

.
Paste this code:

```
{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload": "Hi, I am bot"
  }
}
```

P.S.
Thank you again